# Holo Lens development in unity and windows 7

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-7, hololens

I am trying to develop a sample application for **HoloLens** but the problem is my **Unity build button is disable for UWP build** and it saying that you ***require windows 8 or greater for this build***.

I have checked [HoloLens Development prerequisites and it support Windows-7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/install-the-tools) but I am unable to understand that why I am getting windows-8 error?

And here is the image:

[image]

I have Unity 2017.1.1 and unity 5.6.2, Windows-7, Windows 10 SDK installed in my system.

Comment: Don't you think you should post the error?  Maybe a screenshot of it if it's from the Editor?

Comment: Ok, i will post the screenshot soon

Comment: @PassetCronUs error details has updated with screenshot

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed?

Comment: @sGambolati Yes i have visual studio 2012

Comment: Maybe that the problem. Because you need VS 2015 or later.

Comment: @sGambolati Has nothing to do with Visual Studio. OP is getting error in Unity that says "you need Windows 8 or greater to build the Unity Project". The error is in Unity not Visual Studio. OP cannot generate Visual Studio project from Unity because of that error message which automatically disables the Build buttons in Unity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use Windows 7 when developing Hololens app with Visual Studio through the native way. You cannot use Windows 7 to devdelop Hololens with Unity.

The reason is that Hololens uses UWP and [prerequisites](https://unity3d.com/partners/microsoft/porting-guides) for UWP build in Unity is different from Microsoft's UWP and Prerequisites.

- Windows 8, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10 (recommended)
- Windows App Certification Kit version 10

No Windows 7 mentioned. This is hardcoded into Unity and there may have been good reasons Unity did this. You might be able to circumvent this by patching Unity Editor and removing that check to enable the Build button but I think this will create more problems in the future.

Another option is Windows emulator but I recommend you upgrade to Windows 10.